# Form with a submit button that leads to another form with a yes/no button

Tags: php, html, forms

using php when I press the submit button to send the data to the server, when the script returns I need both a yes and no button to appear to approve or dis approve the data that was sent...Please Help! I got lost at the if/else if statement

```
if (filter_has_var(INPUT_POST, "office")){

$office = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "office");
print "<span>, your office is room $office</span>";
}

if (filter_has_var(INPUT_POST, "os")){
$os = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "os");
print "<span>, and your OS is $os</span>";
}

if($_POST['submit']== 'yes'){
    echo "Thanks!";
}elseif($_POST['submit']=='no'){
    return form(); 
}

else{

//there's no input. Create the form 

print <<< HERE
<form action ="" method="post">
<fieldset>
<label>Enter your name</label> 
<input type = "text"
         name = "name"/><br>
<label>Employee ID</label> 
<input type = "text"
         name = "id"/><br>
<label>Office Room Number</label> 
<input type = "text"
         name = "office"/><br>
<label>Oberating System on the Office Computer</label> 
<input type = "text"
         name = "os"/><br>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
<input type="hidden" name="yes" value="yes">
<input type="hidden" name="no" value="no">
</fieldset> 
</form>
HERE;
}
// end 'value exists' if
?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: would it not be better to approve / disapprove of the data PRIOR to sending the the server to allow the user a chance to alter the content of the data? s

Comment: I need to fill in the form with certain user input such as name, emp ID ex. once i press the submit button to send that data,the server should have that data appear again next to the name, empID ex and I should have a yes and no button approving that data. Im just confused how to have my yes/no buttons appear on that form

Comment: I agree with gagrif that this should be done before you submit, not after, or else you have to re-send the same request, which is kind of pointless.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this in three steps, rather than two:

```
if (yes or no are set as well as the other required form variables){
   // step 3
   // do final submission
} else if (submit and other required form variables are set){
   // step 2
   // A. display data. 
   // B. display form with only yes/no options and no other visible fields
   // C. in form also include original submitted data (as hidden fields)
} else {
   // step 1
   // display empty form with all fields and a submit button
}
```

You can change the second step to combine A and C if you want the form to be editable.

Comment: I appreciate all of you help...I guess I am just really confused on how to add a button on too a hidden form

Comment: @DanWitts You do not need a hidden form. You only need hidden fields. Your submit buttons should not be hidden. For example, in step 1 there should not be any yes or no buttons (not even hidden ones). All buttons, should be of type "submit", not type "hidden". So in step 2 you can either have two submit buttons each with a different name for yes and for no, or have a single submit button with a radio button option for yes or for no.